# Merge tags: lamp and lamp-server

Tags: support, status-completed, merge

LAMP is a server stack, so "lamp-server" seems redundant. (Except in a coal mine, where one might be quite useful.)

Comment: [belongs-on-spelunking.stackexchange]?

Answer (score 1):

Completed; thanks for the suggestion!